# ManagedProperty tag in JSF

Tags: java, jsf-2

In this example, why does it need the @ManagedBean annotation? In the setPalyBean() method, it receives a parameter and set it to the the private variable "playerBean". This is just like a regular Java class design in non-JSF world. Would it work the same if the @ManagedBean is removed?

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class PlayersBean {

  private String playerName;
  private String playerSurname;

  public PlayersBean() {
    playerName = "Rafael";
    playerSurname = "Nadal";
  }

//getters and setters
}

@ManagedBean 
@ViewScoped
public class ProfileBean {

  @ManagedProperty("#{playersBean}")
  private PlayersBean playersBean;
  private String greetings;

  public ProfileBean() {     
  }   

  public void setPlayersBean(PlayersBean playersBean) {
    this.playersBean = playersBean;
  }                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are the rules:

1. `@ManagedBean` - required if you:

   - Want to access your bean from the view, in old-style JSF
   - Want the container to manage the injection of anything into the bean, in old-style JSF
   - Want the container to manage the lifecycle of your bean, ...
   - Want to name your bean something different from the standard class name. The default naming convention is converting the class-name to a standard java, so what you'll have there is a bean named `proileBean`. If you wanted to address that bean by a different name, say `profile`, you'll need to use this annotation
2. `@ManagedProperty` and the associated setter are required, if you want the container to automatically inject anything into your bean. Them's the rules. It boils down to how the injection happens - Reflection.

Will it work without the annotation? No - without that annotation (and depending on your version of JSF; 2.2 allows all kinds of stuff), the container isn't aware of your bean and won't be prompted to take action

You can save yourself the hassle and adopt CDI conventions:

1. Replace `@ManagedBean` with `@Named` (this annotation is required only if you need to access the bean within a page, otherwise, it's unnecessary -Every bean in a CDI context is automatically managed)
2. Replace `@ManagedProperty` with [`@Inject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjban.html). With this annotation, you can ditch the setter and getter altogether. You also don't need to worry about the scope of the bean that you're injecting into or from.
3. Replace your current `@ViewScoped` with the one from [`javax.faces.view.ViewScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/view/ViewScoped.html)

Comment: What would be the CDI version of this example? Thanks.